# Parent key not found, but exists oracle DB

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Before I get started with the error message I want to show a simple left join query for my vendor and product tables:

```
select p.id as ProductId, p.vendorid as VendorFk, v.id as VendorPk
    from Vendors v
        left join products p
        on v.id = p.vendorid;
```

[image]

I ran a similar insert to the one below with success five times prior as you can see by the image above. On try number 6 it seems to fail. I'm not really sure why. I'm brand new to Oracle, i've never had a problem like this before with MS SQL server. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also I'm using Oracle SQL Developer.

-"Error report -
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.FK_VENDORS_ID) violated - parent key not found"

```
insert into products(cost , id , name , partnumber , VendorId)
values(99.99, 6, 'xbox', 'xbox1', 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

- you have two tables: PRODUCTS and VENDORS
- PRODUCTS has a column named VENDORID which is a foreign key that points to VENDORS.ID
- referential integrity means that VENDORS has to contain an ID you're trying to insert into the PRODUCTS table. If it does not, integrity is violated and Oracle raises an error
- in your example, it seems that ID = 2 doesn't exist in the VENDORS table, although image (row #5) suggests different

A short example:

```
SQL> create table vendors (id number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create table products (id number primary key,
  2                         vendorid number constraint fk_pv references vendors);

Table created.

SQL> insert into vendors values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> -- this will be OK as vendors.id = 1 exists
SQL> insert into products values (100, 1);

1 row created.

SQL> -- this will fail as vendors.id = 2 doesn't exist
SQL> insert into products values (200, 2);
insert into products values (200, 2)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SCOTT.FK_PV) violated - parent key not found


SQL>
```

So, what could go wrong? If someone else uses that schema, they might have deleted ID = 2 from the VENDORS table. No problem in doing that, as long as you don't commit inserts into PRODUCTS you've already made (inserts into VENDORS should have been commited already, otherwise that *other user* would have to wait until the lock is released).

P.S. Oh, yes - one more thing: error message says that you're using the SYSTEM schema. Don't do that - SYS and SYSTEM are *special*, they own the database. If you - unintentionally - do something *wrong & unexpected*, you might destroy the database. Create another user (or use one of existing ones, such as HR or SCOTT, if they are pre-installed in the database version you have) and test your skills there.